# Play not running tests

Tags: testing, playframework

I'm working on my first Play! project and for some reason when I run the *test* command, it looks like none of my test are run.

```
Abot::AbotsPlayApp $ play test
[info] Loading project definition from ~/AbotsPlayApp/project
[info] Set current project to AbotsPlayApp (in build file:~/AbotsPlayApp/)
[info] IntegrationTest
[info]
[info]
[info] Total for test IntegrationTest
[info] Finished in 0.0 seconds
[info] 0 tests, 0 failures, 0 errors
[info] ApplicationTest
[info]
[info]
[info] Total for test ApplicationTest
[info] Finished in 0.0 seconds
[info] 0 tests, 0 failures, 0 errors
[info] Passed: : Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0, Skipped 0
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Aug 20, 2013 10:11:14 PM
Abot::AbotsPlayApp $
```

Why does it say "0 tests, 0 failures, 0 errors"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem with 2.1.3 regarding Java tests- please check the Play user forum for the work-around, or use 2.1.4-RC1. Apologies for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Thanks for the response, how stable is 2.1.4RC1?

Comment: I've tried the soultion on the google groups page, now the test will not execute at all, and it will just hang after I run the test command.

Comment: I've tried 2.1.4RC1 just now, it also kept hanging. I realised it was the intergration test (included by default), so I removed that test and my tests run fine (including with the work-around provided for 2.1.3). Seems for some reason the intergration test wasn't running/finishing properly.

Comment: If you can post a link to your project then I may be able to have a look.

Comment: 2.1.4-RC1 is quite stable - we'll also be releasing a 2.1.4-RC2 very shortly.

Comment: I just downloaded your project and ran it with Play 2.1.3 via play test. All was well. Suggest that you pull the project down to another location and try again.

Comment: Thanks, was that with the integration test enabled? Because the tests are now running, just without the integration test.